# get the href value of a specific element and load it

Tags: php, html

I'm using jquery to add `rel=brochure` using `$('.imageOuter a').attr('rel', 'brochure')` this works as expected.

However, I want to grab the link that has `rel` as `brochure`. I'm trying to do this with `loadHTML`, as below:

```
function getBrochureLink() {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($file);
    $area = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
    $links = $area->getElementsByTagName("link");
    foreach($links as $l) {
    if($l->getAttribute("rel") == "brochure") {
            $brochureLink = $l->getAttribute("href");
    }
    }   
}
```

Sadly `$brochureLink` is empty and not grabbing it.

Comment: PHP doesn't execute HTML. If it's a served page, use Ajax. Otherwise, you pretty much can't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the `attr` is set via Javascript. When you retrieved the page's contents via `loadHTML`, the JS was not executed, so you can't find the matching link.

You'll have to either run the JS on the server side, put the `attr` into the DOM directly without JS, or find another architecture for whatever you're attempting to accomplish.